# How to take data from a line and update a field for a point in arcmap?

Tags: python, arcgis, arcmap

So, I have a point and a line on my map (20,000 of them actually). The line has a MATERIAL field that shows the specific type of material and the point has a MATERIAL field that needs to be updated to show the material in the line. The problem is that these two items do not have any connecting fields but they do physically intersect on the map. Any ideas on where I could start? I don't have any work to show because I can't figure out where to even begin with this.

I have been manually updating the fields, but this will take me way too long to complete and I need to automate it. I've looked at modelbuilder but that doesn't really help if you don't know what tools would be useful. I've also looked at the field calculator. I think python is my next option here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use definition queries and ten select by location if anyone is having a similar issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).